# Adding SAS/RAID controller disables network ports. Why?

Tags: networking, network-attached-storage, proxmox, raid-controller

I've built a NAS that has been running well for months. I recently decided to add a `LSI MegaRAID SAS 9260CV-8i L3-25377-02B 8 Port 6GB/S SAS RAID Controller` to it with a couple of additional 12TB HHDs (shucked EasyStores). For some reason, when the SAS/RAID controller is added, my network ports on my `Intel i350-T4` stop working--the lights blink but I don't get any network connectivity.

My NAS runs Proxmox, and when it starts, it says "Failed to raise network interfaces". If I run `journalctl -u networking.service`, it says "Cannot get device ring settings. No such device exists".

I feel like I'm probably missing something obvious as I've never added a SAS or RAID card before. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, just plugging in a new PCIe card changed the interface name. I just needed to `ip link show` to get the new names, then update them in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer. For an answer on workarounds, also see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/353854/146921

Answer (score 0):

After installing a PCI SAS card on my Ubuntu server, my networking also broke, also because my network interface name changed.

On Ubuntu versions 18.04 or above, after getting the new name from `ip link show`, update old references in `/etc/netplan` to the new name, after which the changes have to be applied with `sudo netplan apply`.